# Quickly close mmap discarding unflushed changes

Tags: linux, mmap, virtual-memory

I am using an `mmap`'ed file as a virtual memory arena - the file is manually allocated because I want to control its location. On `munmap`, all the current contents of the buffers are flushed to the file, but I don't really need the file contents. Is it possible to simply discard the mmap area without write back?

Linux-specific solutions are OK.

I mean something like

```
char* myswaparea = "/tmp/myswaparea";
int64_t len = 1LL << 30;
fd = open(myswaparea, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0600);
ftruncate(fd, len);
void* arena = mmap(NULL, len, .... fd ...);
/* use arena */
munmap(arena, len);  /* here comes an unnecessary flush */
close(fd);
unlink(myswaparea);
```

Comment: have you tried ftruncate(fd, 0); ?
Just before munmap...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need / want to write back the changes to the file, just use the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag when you create the map (4th argument to `mmap(2)`).

From the manpage:

> MAP_PRIVATE
>
> Create a private copy-on-write mapping. Updates to the
>   mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and
>   are not carried through to the underlying file. It is unspecified
>   whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in
>   the mapped region.

**EXAMPLE**

```
fd = open("myfile", O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0) {
    /* Handle error... */
}
void *ptr;
size_t len = 1024;
ptr = mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
    /* Handle error... */
}
/* ... */
if (munmap(ptr, len) < 0) {
    /* Handle error... */
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. If I understand correctly, with MAP_PRIVATE, the backing file will never be written - and I want to use it as a private swap area.

Comment: @grep You specifically asked *Is it possible to simply discard the mmap area without write back?* - the answer is `MAP_PRIVATE`. There's no other way to prevent write back to the file - either the map is shared, or it's private. If it's shared, the modifications you make in memory are propagated back to the file; if it's not, they are discarded.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the original poster wants write-back during the run of his program but **not** when his program is exiting.  I'm guessing that because that's what I could use right now. :-)  I have a program that is storing data in file-backed memory for analysis in case the program crashes but if it's exiting cleanly, the file will be deleted so there's no need to flush the data.  So... Is there a "munmap discarding changes" option?